# How does spending cred work when shopping for mission equipment?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, the-sprawl

My players have each bet 3 cred on the assassination mission they've taken, for a total of 9 cred.

During the legwork phase they decide to poison the target, so one of them hits the streets to buy a contact neurotoxin.  Due to bad rolls, this is going to cost them 8 cred.

Does this cred come out of the cred they have leftover after the mission bet, or does it come out of the 9 cred they bet on the mission?

If it came out of the cred bet on the mission, does this affect the results of the *get paid* move at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cred "bet" on your mission is gone; Sprawl p. 127

> After someone has got the job (see Chapter 2: Basic Moves and Chapter 11:
>   Missions), everyone stakes one, two or three points of Cred on the success of the
>   mission. Cross that Cred off your playbook; it’s gone.

So any cred trying to buy gear after that comes out of what the characters have leftover after the mission "bet".

Comment: Ouch, the example on p.128 really doesn't help with this. Everybody starts out with 5 Cred; some people stake 2 and have 3 to spend, and some people stake 3 and have 2 to spend, and it's super easy to get confused as to who has what.

Comment: Yeah, each character should keep track of how many creds they have left and they've "bet" on the job - although I do that usually when running The Sprawl